# How to remove white space around menu div

Tags: html, css

First of all, I know this question has been asked before, but every single answer given is:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

While this works fine for the top header, as shown in the below picture, but it doesn't work on the sidebar / menu.

Is there another solution to this that will still leave my site responsive?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Site Description]

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] so we can see what code you have

Comment: If you are on chrome or firefox, you can press `Ctrl + Shift+ I` to view the boxes of your elements. You will probably be able to identify what are the white borders

Comment: @Xatyrian That did the trick, thanks a million!

Comment: @Coder sorry i meant Shift (Maj is the French word for it ;))

Comment: @Xatyrian Well in that case, merci! :D